# Pass setEagerLoads to Lazy Eager Loading in order to override $with

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

In my project I have Clients Eloquent model that has eager relations configured in class like this:

`protected $with = [ 'phones', 'emails' ];`

Clients also have a relationship with tasks. So on on a task view page

I load the client's name as so:
`$task->load('client')`

The problem is that it loads the phones and emails as well. Is there a way to use setEagerLoads in some way to override the `$with` in this instance?

---

The full snippet

```
/**
 * Display the specified Task.
 *
 * @param Task $task
 */
public function show(Task $task)
{
    $task->load('client');

    return view('task.show', compact('task'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unload realations by passing empty array like  `$task->setRelations([])`

Comment: I need to remove relations from client loaded on parent task, not from $task

Comment: Give more code about your both models and as  well as implemented areas, It will be helpful